# T-568A/B on the same cable

Tags: layer1, cable, cabling, patch-panel

I'm helping my friend punch down all of the Cat5-e cable in his office. Some of it went to existing patch panel and some went directly into a switch.  There are two patch panels, each was about half full.  We punched down about 12 cables into the first patch panel, following the same pinout as the rest - T-568A.  We moved on to the next patch panel and followed the pinout labeled on it, which was T-568-B.  After finishing it, we tested all cables and they worked fine.  Then we realized we probably built some cables that have pinout A on one end and B on the other.  From what I have read, on a 10/100 network (which they are on), having one end be A and one end B doesn't matter.  We obviously have to fix this but I have two questions:

1. On the 10/100 network, will they have any issues using a cable that has one end with pinout A and one end with pinout B?
2. If we have cables with pinout A going from the wall to the patch panel and then we use a Cat6 cable with pinout B from the patch panel to the switch, is that going to cause any problems?  I'm guessing not but just want to confirm.  We are planning on upgrading the switches to 1 Gbps.

Thanks,

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a cable which has the transmit and receive pairs reversed on one end, basically, a crossover cable for 10/100 Mbps. Also, 1 Gbps uses all four pairs. A lot of things today have Auto MDIX, and they should be able to adjust, but not everything does have this, and those things won't work unless you use a crossover patch cable on one end (not both ends) of the horizontal cable.

---

By the way, why go to the expense of Category-6 patch cables if the horizontal cable is Category-5e? This is completely useless, and could lead someone to believe that the horizontal cable is Category-6 when it is not. A cable plant should use the same rating throughout because the rating of the cable plant is the rating of the lowest rated link.